# Does the new Amazon Inspector scan Amazon Lightsail instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail, amazon-inspector

I'm about to enable the new Amazon Inspector on our AWS organization,
My question is does the new Amazon Inspector scans our Amazon Light sail instances? If not, how could we configure our instances to include it to the list of instances to be scanned?

I heard it needs the SSM agent to be able to do vulnerability scanning, however, I do not have access to our light sail instances and would like to know if by default, they would be included to the scanning.

Comment: You would have to treat the Lightsail instances as if they were on-prem instances and connect them to Inspector accordingly.

Comment: I think you need to install SSM agents on your lightsail instance

Comment: I installed SSM agent on my light sail instance, however, Amazon Inspector doesn't seem to detect my light sail instance.